# Error trying to compile Lua with mingw on windows 8

Tags: mingw

I am running Windows 8 (64 bit) and trying to set up Lua following the instructions here: http://www.thijsschreijer.nl/blog/?p=863

[It's not relevant, but the the reason I'm doing this in the first place that I can't get luarocks to work.]

I followed all the instructions to the letter, installing mingw, adding to my path variable, etc.

An error window comes up with the following information:

```
as.exe - Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point libintl_setlocale could not be located in the dynamic link library
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\as.exe
```

Then an error message about "`as.exe has stopped working`"

On the command line it prints:

```
c:\temp\lua-5.1.5>make mingw
cd src && make mingw
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/temp/lua-5.1.5/src'
make "LUA_A=lua51.dll" "LUA_T=lua.exe" \
        "AR=gcc -shared -o" "RANLIB=strip --strip-unneeded" \
        "MYCFLAGS=-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL" "MYLIBS=" "MYLDFLAGS=-s" lua.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/temp/lua-5.1.5/src'
gcc -O2 -Wall -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL   -c -o lua.o lua.c
make[2]: *** [lua.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/temp/lua-5.1.5/src'
make[1]: *** [mingw] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/temp/lua-5.1.5/src'
make: *** [mingw] Error 2
```

I'm totally lost on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I resolved the issue by searching my computer for all files named "libintl-8.dll" and temporarily renaming them. There was another file by the same name in my separate, unrelated "Lua for windows" program files, in the clibs folder. Apparently it interfered somehow.